# Maintain Scroll position after div.toggle (JQUERY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

How do I maintain my page scroll position after JQUERY toggle event, I have searched and researched but couldn't find any solution to remedy this problem.

```
<script src="Scripts/_hideShowDiv/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
             $('#adddriverpanel').hide();

             $('a#adddrivertrigger').click(function () {
                 $('#adddriverpanel').toggle(400);

             });


         });
    </script>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing? .hide() and .toggle() have nothing to do with scroll position, so I think it would help if you explained why the scroll position is a problem. IE: what is changing that is creating an issue? Consider posting a jsfiddle or expanding your code / explanation to include what you are trying to do.

Comment: When I click to show my div, it takes me to the top of my page

Comment: Well, I hate to ask such a silly question but do you by chance have an achor tag (a) within your html that has an id or name of '#adddrivertrigger' as opposed to just 'adddrivertrigger'? To elaborate on what I'm getting at, maybe you should post your HTML because there's nothing in that jquery that should change your scroll position. I'm thinking that there is a # (deeplink) reference in your page that is causing the change in view.

Comment: None, I dont have any id with that name

Comment: Thank you, try the answer I just posted. :)

Comment: I deleted the link for security purposes,  thank you very much!!!!!!!!!! it is working properly noW!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reviewing your code, you simply need to update your html to the following:

```
<a id="adddrivertrigger" href="javascript:void(0);" class="auto-style2">Add Drivers</a>
```

The '#' you had in the link is what is taking you to the top of the page.

If you're going to use an anchor tag with an href for a click event, you need to prevent the href from firing (assuming you don't want it to). You can usually do this with adding

```
return false;
```

To your click event, but better practice for empty href attributes is to create a null javascript call as opposed to a '#'.

For giggles, here are some other things you should /not/ do with href attributes:

```
<a href="javascript:;"></a>
<a href="javascript:return false;"></a>
<a href="javascript://"></a>
<a href=""></a>
<a href="#"></a>
```

All of the above are either invalid javascript or pose inconsistency problems with different browsers.

Another way you could have solved it (via jQuery) is as follows:

```
         $('a#adddrivertrigger').click(function () {
             $('#adddriverpanel').toggle(400);
             return false;
         });
```

Comment: It is working! sorry I have to go out for a while!!!!!! THANKS! I already accepted your answer!! thanks again!!!!!